# libkeybinder error Arch linux

Tags: installation, arch-linux, package-management, compile, key-binding

I am trying to install a package that depends on python-keybinder and hence on libkeybinder. When I run makepkg for libkeybinder, it starts and after sometime I get the following error:

```
checking for XkbQueryExtension... no
configure: error: Could not find XKB
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build libkeybinder.
```

I tried checking the pkgbuild but wasn't able to find anything. :(
Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Which AUR package? If http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=41551 , then it builds fine here. Did you read the comment thread? It looks like it also depends on `pkg-config`, which should be in `base-devel`, and `XkbQueryExtension` is a part of `libx11`, which you'll also need.

Comment: `base-devel` and `libx11` are installed. I am trying to install `pythonkeybinder`

Comment: lib32-libx11 could possibly be a dependency, but that would be odd.  There are, however, multiple AUR packages for `libkeybinder`, the library you said was failing. Is the one you're trying to install the one I linked to? If so, please post the full output from a clean attempt at building via `makepkg` -- use `makepkg -s | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us` if you need a paste service.

Comment: Yes, it's the same library that I am trying to install. This is the output I got by running `makepkg` http://pastebin.com/XKmQcR2J